# Save image without compressing

Tags: java, android, kotlin

in my app, I am taking photo using the camera and I store the image to internal storage but when I retrieve the stored image, the quality of the image is becomes very poor. is there any way to store the actual image without compressing in?

```
private fun saveImage(bitmap: Bitmap):Uri{
    val wrapper = ContextWrapper(applicationContext)
    var file = wrapper.getDir(IMAGE_DIRECTORY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    file = File(file, "${UUID.randomUUID()}.png")

    try {

        val stream: OutputStream = FileOutputStream(file)

        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, stream)
        stream.flush()
        stream.close()
    }catch (e:IOException)
    {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    return Uri.parse(file.absolutePath)
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to remove the bitmap.compress line from your code? or at least set it lower than 100 ?

Comment: Do not use PNG for photos. Use JPEG.

Comment: try JPEG format not PNG

Comment: You are storing a thumbnail of the image. Not the original image. Please start your post with the used camera intent.